# Lombok - @NonNull not working for instance variable read from application.yml file

Tags: spring-boot, pojo, lombok

I am trying to use the `@NonNull` annotation from Lombok to check if my instance variable is not null. Also I am fetching the value of my instance variable using `@Value` annotation of Spring from `application.yml` file. Below is the code with Lombok annotations:

**POJO Class:**

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class Credentials {

    @NonNull
    @Value("${app.username}")
    private String user_name;

    @NonNull
    @Value("${app.password}")
    private String password;

}
```

I am trying to provide a null value in the `application.yml` to check if Lombok throws a null pointer exception, but it fails to throw any exception even when the value is null. Any way we can get Lombok throw the null pointer exception for values getting read from properties file?

Below is my `application.yml` file

**application.yml**

```
app:
    username: '#{null}'
    password: passWord
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with a method breakpoint on the generated setter? I suspect spring is not calling it, but setting the field directly via reflection.

Comment: @JanRieke I did not try debugging but I can see the Getter/Setter methods created in the code structure window.